# how to query a resultset in psql?

Tags: sql, perl, postgresql, count, resultset

Is there a way to query a psql query result that is available as an array in perl?

I am receiving the query result stored in an array. I want to do a select distinct count on type, one of the query result column.

Query result has these column: id, name, type, created_at.

I want to group the result by type and find how many of each type there is.
Is having a loop the only option? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

What kind of an array?  You want the whole result set as a list of arrayrefs?  A list of hashrefs?  You want a single row as a list?   A single row as a hashref?

Typically the simplest way is to loop through:

```
my @results;
while (my $ref = $sth->fetchrow_hashref('NAME_lc')){
    # add some processing here
    push @results, $ref;
}
```

I usually do that because if you want to do any processing on the hashref it's a little cleaner.  However you can also:

```
my @results = $sth->fetchall_hashref('NAME_lc');
```

This is particularly useful if you are sure you don't want processing.